# although i declare 2 variables and pass 2 variables i get too few arguments in function call error

Tags: c, msp430, iar

I am beginner with c. I declare 2 variables and pass 2 variables. So, I didn't understand, why this error occurs.
Also when i remove "0b" from error line code is working

Regards. Here is my main code and function

> Message:Error[Pe165]: too few arguments in function call

```
void transmit(unsigned long data_word, unsigned char number_of_bits); 
//i added this before i call the function
```

```
int main(void) {
  WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer

  init();

  while (1) {
    if ((P2IN & BTN1) == 0) //when button pressed 
    {
      unsigned int j;
      for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        transmit(0b010000100100011, 15); // ERROR OCCURS IN HERE
        delay_ms(40);
      }
      while ((P2IN & BTN1) == 0);
    }
  }
}
```

```
// sending out bits, one by one, LSB first, maximum 16 bits (1 word)
void transmit(unsigned long data_word, unsigned char number_of_bits) 
{
  unsigned char i;
  unsigned int mask;
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_bits; i++) {
    mask = (1 << i);
    if ((data_word & mask) == 0) // bit '0'
    {
      transmitBit0();
    } else // bit '1'
    {
      transmitBit1();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does this error occur? Which function call? Which variables have you declared? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: Please. paste the error from the compiler, so that people with the same error as yours can find the question.

Comment: I compiled your code and did not get 'Too few arguments'.

Comment: Try to add `void transmit(unsigned long data_word, unsigned char number_of_bits);` before the call to transmit. _I think there is a include missing_

Comment: That error message should mention a filename and a line number.

Comment: i pointed out error line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C doesn't have binary literals. `0b...` is not valid C. Some compilers support it as an extension but others do not.

Use hexadecimal notation.